What does it mean that mail mode doesn't support MIME?
I read: "Prior to Emacs 23.2, the default mode was Mail mode, which is similar to Message mode in many respects but lacks features such as MIME support." and also "The most typical thing users want to use the multipart things in MIME for is to add “attachments” to mail they send out." However, mail mode supports attachments: use the mail-add-attachment command to do that.
I'm confused now: what is the relationship between MIME and attachments?

See MIME on Wikipedia. Attachments are only a part, not the whole, of MIME.

Thanks very much! Is there any reference about how mail mode does attachments?

Did you do C-h f mail-add-attachment?

Yes it says it adds it as MIME attachment! I'm super confused! So mail mode has some MIME support? And what MIME things then does it not support?

Yes, it has some MIME support (possibly all of it or as much as message-mode has: the atttachment implementation uses mml-attach-file from mml.el e.g. and there seems to be some evidence that it supports non-ASCII characters). But there are a dozen RFCs (see Wikipedia page) that define (or redefine) various aspects of MIME and unless you go through them all, you cannot know for sure what it supports or does not support. You can ask for clarification on gnu.emacs.help and maybe  even decide that the statement your quoted is ...

... a doc bug and needs to be fixed. I don't know one way or another but I don't see why any of this is confusing: it's more or less standard fare for all software. In addition to the mailing list, you might decide to start a discussion on Redit (r/emacs), but it is unlikely that anybody will volunteer to do a detailed check list if they don't know the answer already. Your best bet for that is to find and ask the person(s) who ported the mml changes to sendmail.el (the mail-mode implementation).
